# Linking two repositories in git

Tags: git, github

We have a set of git repositories where our product is developed. These repositories are managed in bitbucket or gitlab and hosted on-prem or cloud. Changes done to these repo's need to be propagated periodically (say once a month) to a set of public repo's hosted in github. This requirement is there to support our beta program where we test out changes before making it public (making it GA). Are there any standard patterns that can be used for this purpose?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: You can do it manually once a month as you describe, use a periodic job as described in one answer, or use repository mirroring. I haven't used mirroring but I'd expect to be able to sync based on tags or branches, so you could tag/merge changes when they go out of beta and get those automatically mirrored.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the Bitbucket repository to your local machine:

```
$ git clone --mirror ssh://git@bitbucket.org:your_name/your_repo.git
```

Then you basically have to run these two commands every month:

```
$ git remote update --prune
$ git push --mirror git@github.com:your_name/your_repo.git
```

### Linux and Cron

If you have a Linux machine/Linux server/WSL edit your [crontabs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cron):

```
$ crontab -e
```

Add this crontab:

```
@monthly git -C <local_repo_path> remote update --prune && git -C <local_repo_path> push --mirror git@github.com:your_name/your_repo.git
```

### macOS and Cron

Automating tasks using Cron is very similar to the way it's done in Linux, follow [this guide](https://medium.com/macoclock/automate-running-a-script-using-crontab-on-macos-88a378e0aeac) to get started.

### Windows and Scheduled Task

I am not very familiar with [Schtasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.10/cc772785(v=ws.10)), but I this is how you would automate the task:

```
> schtasks /create /tn git-mirror /tr git -C <local_repo_path> remote update --prune && git -C <local_repo_path> push --mirror git@github.com:your_name/your_repo.git /sc weekly /d MON /ru "System"
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.